# dojo.xhrGet handle as javascript ie8 not returning

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

I have:

```
dojo.xhrGet({
    url:"/data/js/1/markers.js",
    handleAs:"javascript",
    load: function(r){
        dojo.forEach(placemarks, function(item) {
```

Which works fine in Chrome, FF and Safari but not IE. Error `placemarks` is undefined is given. If I log `r` it gives me the first object in my array `placemarks`.

Am I missing something with IE or do I need to set a special header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dojo doesn't eval javascript globably when it comes back, so any variables must be assigned to the window:

```
window.placemarks = ...
```